# How can i send all the fields from database in the java file to another java file?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, spinner, bundle

i have an simple car database like this:

```
db.addCar(new Car("Alfa Romeo","Giulietta","1.4 TB Distinctive","Benzine","1.4","120","2012","5","1465","4351","54000"));
        db.addCar(new Car("Audi","A6","2.0 TDi","Diesel","2.0","170","2012","6","1455","4915","183600"));
        db.addCar(new Car("BMW","7 Series","7.30 ID Comfort","Benzine","3.0","245","2012","6","1450","4835","528000"));
        db.addCar(new Car("Chevrolet","Captiva","2.0 LT AT","Diesel","2.0","163","2012","6","1756","4673","79950"));
        db.addCar(new Car("Citroen","C5","1.6 HDi Comfort","Diesel","1.6","112","2012","5","1458","4779","67430"));
```

i'am using 3 spinners to choose first three column (make,model,type) and also i can send them to my result xml page with this method

```
b3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
             @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View comparePage2, MotionEvent event) {

                 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Compare2.class);
                    //Create a bundle object
                    Bundle car = new Bundle();

                    //Inserts a String value into the mapping of this Bundle
                    car.putString("make", spinner_make.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    car.putString("model", spinner_model.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    car.putString("type", spinner_type.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    car.putString("make2", spinner_make2.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    car.putString("model2", spinner_model2.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    car.putString("type2", spinner_type2.getSelectedItem().toString());


                    //Add the bundle to the intent.
                    intent.putExtras(car);


                    //start the DisplayActivity
                    startActivity(intent);

                return false;
                }

private void loadSpinnerData() {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        List <String> makers = db.getAllMakers();
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, makers);

        List <String> models = db.getAllModels();
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, models);

        List <String> types = db.getAllTypes();
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, types);

        List <String> makers2 = db.getAllMakers();
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, makers2);

        List <String> models2 = db.getAllModels();
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, models2);

        List <String> types2 = db.getAllTypes();
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter6 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, types2);


        spinner_make.getContext();

// Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

// attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner_make.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner_model.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
        spinner_type.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);
        spinner_make2.setAdapter(dataAdapter4);
        spinner_model2.setAdapter(dataAdapter5);
        spinner_type2.setAdapter(dataAdapter6);


}
```

but how can i send other fields to that xml page with the same method ?

Comment: By adding more key-value pairs to the `Bundle car`, similar to what you're already doing for `make`, `model` and `type`. However, since it looks like you have a `Car` object, it might just be easier to make that implement `Serializable` (or `Parcelable`) and put the whole object in the `Bundle`, in stead of every field value individually.

Comment: for example, if i choose audi a6 2.0 TDI by using spinners, how can i send other fields of this car to other file?

Comment: Well, you're probably doing a database query somewhere to fill the adapters for the 3 spinners? That's where you should have all the data you need. Ideally `getSelectedItem()` will return a `Car` object, which you can then simply pass on to the next activity (since it contains all fields). In order to further help you, please show the code where you get the data from the database and initialise the spinner adapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: you'll need to retrieve all the data that you want to send through to the next `Activity` from the database. That being said, I'd probably make the following changes to accomplish that:

**1. Get all (required) data from database**

In your `DatabaseHandler` class, create a method that returns all cars, by doing the inverse of your first code snippet. Or at least return all the data you need in the next `Activity`. I'm going to assume you'll be returning all data here:

```
Cursor c = // TODO: implement: query database for car data
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
    cars.add(new Car(...)); // add every car
}
```

**2. Have `Car` implement `Serializable`.**

Change the definition of your `Car` class to extend `Serializable`. That should be no problem, assuming the class is just a collection of simple fields:

```
public class Car implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1234567890L;

    // constructor(s), fields, getters, setters below
}
```

**3. Get the selected car from the spinner**

For the sake of this example, I'm just going to get the car from the original collection in step 1 by using the selected position and put that into the `Intent` (no need to create a separate `Bundle` for that):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Compare2.class);
Car selectedCar = cars.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
intent.putSerializableExtra("selected_car", selectedCar);
```

You can do this for multiple single cars, or even a whole collection (provided that collection also implements `Serializable`; i.e. `ArrayList`). On the receiving end, you can retrieve the data doing the opposite of above:

```
Car selectedCar = (Car) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("selected_car");
```

---

Now, your code snippets suggest that you're going to compare the specifications of different cars in the next `Activity`. If that's the case, then you probably won't have to change a lot to above. I would consider changing the adapters to get their data from the `cars` collection, rather then querying the database again for a single column of data you already have - that should be a straightforward change.

If you have some sort of filtering going on, based on the selection of the different spinners, then you'll want to make sure that your method that returns all the data for the cars takes this selection into account. I'll leave it up to you to figure out those details yourself.